# Angular 2: how to provide `--module system --experimentalDecorators` flags?

Tags: typescript, angular, rubymine

I'm having a trouble with compilling my TypeScript file:

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Messenger</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

TypeScript Compiller returns

```
Error:(1, 1) TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
Error:(1, 25) TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
Error:(7, 14) TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
```

Providing flags in tsconfig.json does nothing.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**My project tree:**

```
.
├── app
├── node_modules
├── typings
├── application.js
├── messages.js
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── typings.json
```

I'm using RubyMine 8 as IDE

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to provide my flags?

Comment: A few ideas: (1) make sure you have at least typescript 1.5, which is when support for tsconfig.json was added, (2) make sure you are not invoking tsc from a folder that is a parent of your project (tsc will search up but not down for a tsconfig.json file, (3) make sure you are not invoking tsc with input files on the command line (causes tsconfig.json to be ignored). If none of these help, can you provide some details about how you are executing tsc?

Comment: Which TypeScript compiler are you using? The one bundled with RubyMine or with the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the bundled TypeScript compiler, go to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript`

You can click on the `set options manually` radio button, and enter the arguments in the `Command line options` text box. [See the list of available arguments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options)

[image: webstorm typescript configuration]

This is how you provide command line arguments.

`Use tsconfig.json` works for me without providing any command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but I think there're two errors in your first line of your app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

should be

```
import { Component } from '@angular2/core';
```

The space between the imports and the curly brackets and the '@' symbol before angular2 have caused me lots and lots of pain.

Comment: I asked this question when Angular 2 was an early beta, so syntax might change.